# SweetAlert text formatting

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am using sweetAlert for dialog box display. Inside my dialog box, I have to display a large string with line breaks in between. My sample string is as follows:

```
var str="Task1Name          :    Success  :   statusCode\n 
         Task2NameLonger    :    Failed   :   statusCode\n"
```

and so on. So, basically, I want each of them in a new line and the spaces matched. When I use sweetalert dialog box line breaks are showing up properly but the text is aligned to the centre automatically and spacing is truncated. Can someone help me to manually set my alignment and spacing?

Comment: You can set the text as html and use a borderless table

Comment: @AlonEitan The str is a variable which is filled dynamically depending on when a button is clicked. I am not sure if I can do it, Will try and update! I think it should be possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Wrapping a string into `<pre>` tag could be a solution:

```js
var str="Task1Name          :    Success  :   statusCode\n" +
        "Task2NameLonger    :    Failed   :   statusCode\n";
         
Swal.fire({
  html: '<pre>' + str + '</pre>',
  customClass: {
    popup: 'format-pre'
  }
});
```

```css
.format-pre pre {
  background: #49483e;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

---

PS. The original sweet alert plugin is unsupported, I suggest you using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) plugin.

Migration is simple, here's the migration guide: [Migration from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with this for 2 hours

Answer (score 24):

If you switch to sweetalert2, you can use html instead of text:

```
swal({ title: 'hi', html: 'First line<br>Second line' });
```

Comment: Html key  depricated now

Answer (score 2):

I also have to show (a lot of) text with swal(2) and want to show the most of the text **left** aligned and the last line centered.
First, I have tried to apply css with `customClass: 'swal-breit',` 
and set the width and alignment in the css.
But this don't work for my case...

As css don't seems to work for my case, I have implemented it with **HTML (paragraph and align)**. In my (juery) function (with the embedded swal), I first create a **variable** with the html code and then set the property `html:` to the variable.
Short description:
First a lot of text is showed (left aligned), then a question is showed (centered).
If the user clicks 'Ja' (Yes), a specific page (view) is loaded, if he clicks 'Nein' (No), nothing happens (swal ist closed an the user remains on the page (view).

**Code snipped(simplified to post here) (German):**

```
function MySwalFunction() {
  var Meldungstext = "";
  Meldungstext = Meldungstext + '<p align="left"> text in paragraph here.. <strong>strong text kere...</strong> further normal text with line break. <br>'
  Meldungstext = Meldungstext + 'Second line of text </p>'
  Meldungstext = Meldungstext + '<p align="left"> second paragraph block.. with linebreak <br>'
  Meldungstext = Meldungstext + 'second line to second block </p>' 
  Meldungstext = Meldungstext + '<p align="left">tex ti third paragraph here </p>'
  Meldungstext = Meldungstext + '<strong>Last line WITHOUT paragraph = is showed centered (swal default) </strong>'

  swal.fire({
    title: '! Achtung !',
    html: Meldungstext,
    icon: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    width: '90%',
    confirmButtonColor: 'blue',
    cancelButtonText: 'Nein',
    confirmButtonText: 'Ja',
  }).then(function (result) {
    if (result.value) {
      var hostname = window.location.origin;
      var xlink = hostname + "/main/sub/"
      location.href = xlink;
    }
    else {
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use **\n** to break to new line